# serious performance problem with jquery find in firefox

Tags: jquery, performance, firefox

Here's a simple pice of jQuery code:

```
alert($(document).find("*").length);
alert($(document).find("v\\:group").length);
alert($(document).find("v\\:group").find("*").length);
```

In non-firefox browsers, all 3 steps return instantaneously; in firefox 3.6 the third step seems to take forever (I let it run for over a minute at 100% CPU and it didn't finish). I'm using the latest jQuery (1.5.1) but had the same results in 1.4.2.

The counts returned are 10000, 50, and 2000 so you can see that whilst the document is not trivial in size, it shouldn't be big enough to present a significant performance problem like that.

In response to the previous posts, I'd just like to clarify a bit more: the document is HTML containing some embedded VML (which is IE specific). I know that jquery doesn't support namespaces properly but I had gathered that this is the best way to search for nodes outside the HTML namespace in jQuery.

What I'm stumped on is that even though I understand performance of find("*") is not great, I don't see how it can take such a huge amount of time to find 2000 nodes when document.find(*) finds 10000 nodes instantaneously

Comment: can you tell me what "v\\:group" selects exactly?

Comment: Using `find("*")` is something I'd avoid in all circumstances. If you really need to reach all descendant nodes, it would be more sensible to just traverse the tree "manually".

Comment: Isn't v:\\group something to do with VML?

Comment: @meo: It would select all notes with the name `v:group` - which wouldn't be valid HTML, but it's a perfectly valid XML tag name.

Comment: @RoToRa: since the op looks up descendents from `document` it is HTML and therefore invalid anyway.

Comment: @jAndy: Couldn't it be XHTML with embedded (inline) XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got to the bottom of this. Turns out jQuery is innocent; it's because firefox parses the HTML differently. It seems that if you have some "HTML" source like this:

```
<v:group />
<v:group />
<v:group />
```

Firefox builds the DOM like this:

```
<v:group>
    <v:group>
        <v:group />
    </v:group>
</v:group>
```

so `$(document).find("v\\:group").find("*")`  turns from O(n) to O(n^2), hence the big difference in performance in my document with thousands of `<v:group>`s in.

I would have hoped firefox would have parsed it the same as other browsers but i'll stop short of calling it a bug because I don't think this is valid HTML.

Comment: What MIME type are you using? Unless you are using `application/xhtml+xml`, Firefox wouldn't know it's X(HT)ML, and would use it's HTML parser instead of the XML parser.

Comment: And the HTML parser ignores the /s, so the only way to close an unknown tag is to use a full close tag `</v:group>`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Firefox routine to travers the dom and return the nodes is not very performant. It semms like it can't be jQueries fault, cause other Browsers seem to handle it better.

Comment: Might be an idea to suggest it to jQuery, but it might just be a firefox thing, sadly.